# Create Outlook appointment in shared calendar

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following code set up to create appointments in Outlook from data on my Excel spreadsheet. What I would like to do id make the appointment in a shared calendar rather than my own default one.

The calendar I want to add it to is the DTS Streetworks one as shown here - https://ibb.co/tKXKSPX, but I have no idea how to go about it.

```
Sub CoringAdd()

    Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, _
    r As Long, i As Long, wb As ThisWorkbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = wb.Sheets("Coring")
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application

    r = ES.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To r
        With ES.Cells(i, 10)
            If .Value = "No" And ES.Cells(i, 7) <> "Yes" Then
                ES.Cells(i, 7) = "Yes"
                With OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
                    .Subject = "Send reminder email - LBRuT " + ES.Cells(i, 2).Value
                    .Start = ES.Cells(i, 6) + 1 + ES.Cells(i, 8).Value
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                    .Body = "£" & ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    .Save
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next i

    Set OL = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ES = Nothing

End Sub
```

UPDATE:

Latest code below, still goes to default calendar.

```
Sub ResolveName()

Dim OL As Outlook.Application, ES As Worksheet, _
    r As Long, i As Long, wb As ThisWorkbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = wb.Sheets("Licences")
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("DTS Streetworks")
    myRecipient.Resolve


    r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To r
        With Cells(i, 5)

         If myRecipient.Resolved And .Value = "Mobile Plant" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
    With OL.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
                    .Subject = "Test " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value
                    .Start = ES.Cells(i, 14) + ES.Cells(i, 15).Value
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                    .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    .Save
    End With
    End If
    End With
    Next i
End Sub

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
    CalendarFolder.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding your update: You still create the appointment with `Outlook.Application.CreateItem`, which is wrong. You need to create it with `someReferenceToTheCalendarFolder.Items.Add`, as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the shared calendar by using the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. For example:

```
Sub ResolveName()
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")
    myRecipient.Resolve
    If myRecipient.Resolved Then
        Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
    End If
End Sub

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
    CalendarFolder.Display
End Sub
```

When you get a shared calendar folder you may use the [Items.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.add) method which creates a new Outlook item in the `Items` collection for the folder. You just need to pass an item type you need to create, for example, `olAppointmentItem`.

```
Set myItem = mySharedCalendarFolder.Items.Add olAppointmentItem
```

So, your code should look like this:

```
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ES = wb.Sheets("Licences")

    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olAppItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("DTS Streetworks")
    myRecipient.Resolve

    If myRecipient.Resolved Then
        Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
        r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 5 To r
           With Cells(i, 5)
             If .Value = "Mobile Plant" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" Then
                Set olAppItem = CalendarFolder.Items.Add olAppointmentItem
                With olAppItem 
                    .Subject = "Test " + ES.Cells(i, 4).Value
                    .Start = ES.Cells(i, 14) + ES.Cells(i, 15).Value
                    .ReminderSet = True
                    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60
                    .Body = ES.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    .Save
                End With
             End If
         End With
       Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I've got it to open the right calendar but still can't get it to make the appointment in it, it just goes into my default calendar?

Comment: What code do you have now? Did you try to use the sample code?

Comment: Updated in original post

Comment: I don't see where you create a new appointment in the shared folder.

Comment: I can't work out how to do so, I can only seem to get it in the default calendar